# Why $\phi :K \rightarrow K[X]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is one to one?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a field and $f(x)\in K[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial,let  $\phi :K \rightarrow K[X]/\langle f(X)\rangle$
with $\phi(\lambda)=\lambda+ \langle f(X)\rangle$
I am not sure I understand  correctly why $\phi$ is $1$-$1$.

$\phi(\lambda)=\phi(\mu)\Rightarrow \mu+\langle f(X)\rangle=\lambda+\langle f(X)\rangle $ because $\langle f(X)\rangle $ is an ideal, $\lambda-\mu\in\langle f(X)\rangle  \Rightarrow ? \lambda =\mu$ because $f(X)|\mu-\lambda$ only if $\lambda=\mu$.

Is this true because $\mu,\lambda\in K$, so they are constant polynomials in $K[X]$ and because $f$  is not a constant polynomial, this can be true only if $\mu-\lambda=0$ . Am I understanding this correctly ?

Comment: Yes indeed, this follows from $\text{deg}(fg) = \text{deg}(f) + \text{deg}(g) \geq \text{deg}(f) \geq 1$ for any $g \in K[X]$ non-zero.

Comment: In fact, any ring homomorphism from a field to a nonzero ring must be one-to-one.

Comment: This proof generalizes a bit better though, it still works if one replaces the field $K$ with an integral domain.

Comment: I edited your post, please take a minute to compare the two versions. Most importantly, you used $x$ for a generic element of $K$ and for your variable. Note also you do not need $f$ irreducible for this to work.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308085/mapping-from-f-to-e-where-f-is-a-field-and-e-fx-langle-px-rangle